# Can not Open Ethereum Wallet on Window 10

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, error

I did trying install soft Ethereum wallet on windows 10, But I can't open the program. It looks like the picture below. Help me pls, Thank everyone.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The official Ethereum Wallet (and Mist) [have been deprecated for a while](https://medium.com/@avsa/sunsetting-mist-da21c8e943d2), and it's not recommended to use them anymore. You can find some alternative options on the Ethereum website [here](https://ethereum.org/en/wallets/). If you're looking for a desktop wallet, I recommend MyCrypto's desktop application. It's fully open-source (see [GitHub](https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto)), and you can download it from https://download.mycrypto.com. It works on Windows, as well as macOS and Linux-based systems.